# Documenting Get/Post Parameters with Doxygen or PHPDoc

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen, phpdoc

I was looking through the documentation for PHPDoc and could not find a good way to document the Post variables I was sending to various methods.

So, I started to look into Doxygen with the hopes that it would provide me with a better way to document all of these variables. My code involves a lot of AJAX requests, so most of the variables are sent through post.

Is there a good way for me to document the post variables in doxygen? I'm having trouble determining whether I'll get an error just running with the standard parameter tag.

If not, is there another documentor that might be helpful in this process? Or should I just manually document everythign and ignore looking for an automatic documenting tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the methods are reading those directly from $_POST, rather than as method arguments, then I'd lean on the [@uses](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/uses.html) tag in the method's docblock:

```
/**
 * My foo() method
 * @return void
 * @uses $_POST['bar'] directly
 */
public function foo()
{
    echo "I use ", $_POST['bar'], "... :-)";
}
```

Another option might be the @global tag:

```
/**
 * My bar() method
 * @return void
 * @global mixed uses the 'bar' key from the $_POST superglobal directly
 */
public function foo()
{
    global $_POST;
    echo "I use ", $_POST['bar'], "... :-)";
}
```

I realize that the "global" keyword is not technically necessary for a superglobal inside a method, but it does help get it documented.

---

**Edit**

Note that according to PHPDoc's reference guide, [@uses](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/uses.html) is intended to show a two-way relationship.

> Documentation generators SHOULD create a @used-by tag in the documentation of the receiving element that links back to the element associated with the @uses tag

Thus, although semantically @uses might read better, [@see](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html) could also be used to document a $_[POST|GET|REQUEST] parameter. The main/only difference between the two is that @see is meant to be a one-way link to the [FQSEN](https://docs.phpdoc.org/2.9/glossary.html#term-fqsen) being referenced in the doc block

Comment: Thanks, I think the @uses is a good idea! Global sounds like it may be a little annoying to add everywhere, but I'll look into that if the other way doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, sorry this is kind of late, but I'm new to PHP DOC. I used @uses, but I had a small issue. The documentor's API shows only the method name then the function. It doesn't show the description after. How do I make the description show up? Currently, it just looks like USES    |     CLASSNAME/FUNCTIONNAME/VARIABLE. But, I want the description to show up afterword.